# What happens to documents saved locally when they are deleted or unshared remotely

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I am looking everywhere to understand how it works. Basically, I have some files I do not want to share anymore with some coworkers. I have revoked the permissions on Google Drive web interface. Now the question is simple: what happens if these documents were synced with a Google Drive app on Windows?

Do the files get deleted as well from the local machine on which they are synced or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the files do infact get removed. This is the whole idea of the syncing feature. As long as Google Drive **is running** and there an internet connection, then the files will be synced with the server. Part of the sync process is adding **AND** removing files, so that the files appear as they do in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the Google Drive App. Not exactly the answer to your question but try [Google Backup and Sync](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/) instead. Using that you can specifically select **which folders to be synced** with your Google Drive storage and you can stop a set of selected folders from syncing anymore after it has been synced(if you want). Also, by this option '**Don’t remove items everywhere**' under *Preferences*, you can ensure that your synced content will not be deleted even if you delete them from your original location.

Refer to this answer as well: 
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130712/195865