# Google Backup and Sync - Only One Direction

Tags: google-drive, backup

I am using 'Google Backup and Sync', to sync a directory in my local machine with my Google Drive storage. **After** the sync has completed for the **first** time,

1. I deleted some of the content in my **local** directory(which the content have already been synced to Google Drive).
2. Then I added some new content to my **local** directory.
3. Afterward, I ran Sync again(for the new content to be synced into Google Drive).
   However, it not only uploaded the new content to my Google Drive but also detected that some of the content in my local directory is missing and tried to download those missing content from Google Drive.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to achieve my goal, without the missing content being downloaded to my local machine. (i.e : Sync only in one direction)?
2. I need to be sure that whatever happens to my local directory, the synced content in Google Drive will not be *deleted*. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. One-way sync is not possible with Google Backup and Sync.
   I believe there are other synchronization programs that you can synchronize in only one direction.

.

2. You can set up in 'Backup and Sync' that items from your local directory will not be deleted from the Google Drive cloud.

So:

> 1. On your computer, click Backup and Sync [image]
> 2. Click More [image] [image] **Preferences**.
> 3. Next to "Removing items," click the Down arrow Down [image]:
>
>    - **Don’t remove items everywhere**: When you delete something on your computer, it will stay on drive.google.com.
> 4. Click **OK**.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374987

Comment: Where is this option "Backup and sync", can't find it